# Java Swing - GUI freezes when completing calculations after clicking a button

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, freeze, calculation

I have created a scientific calculator program. What my program does is take "label" which is the string inputted by the user using buttons and evaluate the expression. What my program does is, as soon as the equal button (button_eq) is clicked, it calls the splitLabel method which splits the label into an Arraylist of numbers and operators. It then calls brackets which searches for brackets within the ArrayList and completes sub calculations by calling the method calculate. However, before when my program was handling more basic calculations (addition, subtraction) it was working fine. However, as soon as I added more complex calculations the program freezes when I click the equals button. I was wondering what the issue could be?

```
  public class CalculatorFrameA {
      ActionListener button_eqListener = new ActionListener(){
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
          label2.setText(bracket(splitLabel(label.getText())));
      }
  };

    public ArrayList<String> splitLabel(String val){
        ArrayList<String> label_split = new ArrayList<String>();
        String value = "";
        String op = "";

        for (int i = 0; i< val.length(); i++){
            boolean isDigit = Character.toString(val.charAt(i)).matches("[0123456789.]+");
            boolean isOperator = Character.toString(val.charAt(i)).matches("[+*/^-]+");
            boolean isSin = (Character.toString(val.charAt(i)).equals("s") && Character.toString(val.charAt(i+1)).equals("i") && Character.toString(val.charAt(i+2)).equals("n"));
            boolean isCos = (Character.toString(val.charAt(i)).equals("c") && Character.toString(val.charAt(i+1)).equals("o") && Character.toString(val.charAt(i+2)).equals("s"));
            boolean isTan = (Character.toString(val.charAt(i)).equals("t") && Character.toString(val.charAt(i+1)).equals("a") && Character.toString(val.charAt(i+2)).equals("n"));
            boolean isOpBracket = Character.toString(val.charAt(i)).equals("(");
            boolean isClBracket = Character.toString(val.charAt(i)).equals(")");  

                while (isDigit){
                    value = value + Character.toString(val.charAt(i));
                }

                if (isOperator && !value.equals("")){
                    op = Character.toString(val.charAt(i));
                    label_split.add(value);
                    label_split.add(op);
                    op = "";
                    value = "";
                } else if (isOperator && value.equals("")){
                    if (Character.toString(val.charAt(i)).equals("-")){
                        value = Character.toString(val.charAt(i));
                    }
                } else if (isSin){
                    label_split.add("sin");
                }else if (isCos){
                    label_split.add("cos");
                }else if (isTan){
                    label_split.add("tan");
                } else if (isOpBracket && !value.equals("")){
                    label_split.add(value);
                    label_split.add("(");
                    value = "";
                } else if (isOpBracket && value.equals("")){
                    label_split.add("(");
                } else if (isClBracket && !value.equals("")){
                    label_split.add(value);
                    label_split.add(")");
                    value = "";
                }
            if (i== val.length()-1 && !value.equals("")){
                label_split.add(value);
            } else if (i== val.length()-1 && Character.toString(val.charAt(i)).equals(")")){
                label_split.add(")");
            }
        } return label_split;
    }   
    public String bracket(ArrayList<String> label_split){
        ArrayList<Integer> opBra = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> clBra = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<String> calculation = new ArrayList<String>();
        int counter = 0;
        int counter1 = 0;

        if (label_split.contains("(") && label_split.contains(")")){
            for (int j=0; j<label_split.size(); j++){
                if (label_split.get(j).equals("(")){
                    counter = counter + 1;
                    opBra.add(j);
                } else if (label_split.get(j).equals(")")){
                    counter1 = counter1 + 1;
                    clBra.add(j);
                }
            } 
            if (counter1 != counter){
                return "error missing bracket";
            } else {
                for (int j=opBra.size(); j>0; j--){
                    int opBraPos = opBra.get(j) + 1; //+1 and -1 so it doesn't include ()
                    int clBraPos = clBra.get(opBra.size()-j) - 1;
                    opBra.remove(j);
                    clBra.remove(opBra.size()-j);

                    for(int t = 0; t < (clBraPos - opBraPos); t++){
                        calculation.add(label_split.get(t+opBraPos));
                    }

                    String value = calculate(calculation);
                    label_split.set(j , value);
                    calculation.clear();

                    for (int n = 0; n < ((clBraPos+1) - opBraPos); n++){
                        label_split.remove(n);
                    }
                }
            }
            return calculate(label_split);
        } else{
            return calculate(label_split);
        } 
    }
    public String calculate(ArrayList<String> calculation){
        double value = 0.0;
        String value1 = "";
        boolean isOperator = calculation.contains("[+*/^-]+");  
        boolean isSin =  calculation.contains("sin");
        boolean isCos = calculation.contains("cos");
        boolean isTan = calculation.contains("tan");
        boolean isOpBracket = calculation.contains("(");
        boolean isClBracket = calculation.contains(")");

        for (int i=0; i < calculation.size(); i++){
            if (calculation.get(i).equals("^") && i < calculation.size() && i < 0){
                boolean isDigit1 = calculation.get(i-1).matches("[0123456789.-]+");
                boolean isDigit2 = calculation.get(i+1).matches("[0123456789.-]+");
                if (isDigit1 && isDigit2){
                    value = Math.pow(Double.parseDouble(calculation.get(i-1)), Double.parseDouble(calculation.get(i+1)));
                    value1 = Double.toString(value);
                    calculation.set(i,value1);
                    calculation.remove(i-1);
                    calculation.remove(i+1);
                }
            }
        }

        for (int a=0; a < calculation.size(); a++){
            if ( (calculation.get(a)).equals("sin") && a < calculation.size() && a < 0){
                boolean isDigit1 = calculation.get(a+1).matches("[0123456789.-]+");
                if (isDigit1){
                    value = Math.sin(Double.parseDouble(calculation.get(a+1)));
                    value1 = Double.toString(value);
                    calculation.set(a,value1);
                    calculation.remove(a+1);
                }
            }
        }

        for (int b=0; b < calculation.size(); b++){
            if ( (calculation.get(b)).equals("cos") && b < calculation.size() && b < 0){
                boolean isDigit1 = calculation.get(b+1).matches("[0123456789.-]+");
                if (isDigit1){
                    value = Math.cos(Double.parseDouble(calculation.get(b+1)));
                    value1 = Double.toString(value);
                    calculation.set(b,value1);
                    calculation.remove(b+1);
                }
            }
        }

        for (int c=0; c < calculation.size(); c++){
            if ( (calculation.get(c)).equals("tan") && c < calculation.size() && c < 0){
                boolean isDigit1 = calculation.get(c+1).matches("[0123456789.-]+");
                if (isDigit1){
                    value = Math.tan(Double.parseDouble(calculation.get(c+1)));
                    value1 = Double.toString(value);
                    calculation.set(c,value1);
                    calculation.remove(c+1);
                }
            }
        }

        for (int d=0; d < calculation.size(); d++){
            if (calculation.get(d).equals("*") && d < calculation.size() && d < 0){
                boolean isDigit1 = calculation.get(d-1).matches("[0123456789.-]+");
                boolean isDigit2 = calculation.get(d+1).matches("[0123456789.-]+");
                if (isDigit1 && isDigit2){
                    value = Double.parseDouble(calculation.get(d-1)) * Double.parseDouble(calculation.get(d+1));
                    value1 = Double.toString(value);
                    calculation.set(d,value1);
                    calculation.remove(d-1);
                    calculation.remove(d+1);
                }
            }
        }   

        for (int e=0; e < calculation.size(); e++){
            if (calculation.get(e).equals("/") && e < calculation.size() && e < 0){
                boolean isDigit1 = calculation.get(e-1).matches("[0123456789.-]+");
                boolean isDigit2 = calculation.get(e+1).matches("[0123456789.-]+");
                if (isDigit1 && isDigit2){
                    value = Double.parseDouble(calculation.get(e-1)) / Double.parseDouble(calculation.get(e+1));
                    value1 = Double.toString(value);
                    calculation.set(e,value1);
                    calculation.remove(e-1);
                    calculation.remove(e+1);
                }
            }
        }   

        for (int f=0; f < calculation.size(); f++){
            if (calculation.get(f).equals("+") && f < calculation.size() && f < 0){
                boolean isDigit1 = calculation.get(f-1).matches("[0123456789.-]+");
                boolean isDigit2 = calculation.get(f+1).matches("[0123456789.-]+");
                if (isDigit1 && isDigit2){
                    value = Double.parseDouble(calculation.get(f-1)) + Double.parseDouble(calculation.get(f+1));
                    value1 = Double.toString(value);
                    calculation.set(f,value1);
                    calculation.remove(f-1);
                    calculation.remove(f+1);
                }
            }
        }   

        for (int g=0; g < calculation.size(); g++){
            if (calculation.get(g).equals("-") && g < calculation.size() && g < 0){
                boolean isDigit1 = calculation.get(g-1).matches("[0123456789.-]+");
                boolean isDigit2 = calculation.get(g+1).matches("[0123456789.-]+");
                if (isDigit1 && isDigit2){
                    value = Double.parseDouble(calculation.get(g-1)) - Double.parseDouble(calculation.get(g+1));
                    value1 = Double.toString(value);
                    calculation.set(g,value1);
                    calculation.remove(g-1);
                    calculation.remove(g+1);
                }
            }
        }   

        for (int h=0; h < calculation.size(); h++){
            boolean isDigit = calculation.get(h).matches("[0123456789.-]+");
            if (isDigit && !isOperator && !isSin && !isCos && !isTan &&!isOpBracket &&!isClBracket){
                double value3 = 0.0;
                value3 = Double.parseDouble(calculation.get(h));
                String value2 = Double.toString(value3);
                calculation.set(h,value2);
            }
        }

        return calculation.get(0);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CalculatorFrameA g = new CalculatorFrameA();
    }
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CalculatorFrameA g = new CalculatorFrameA();
    }
```

Comment: i guess you should do the calculations in an extra thread so the main thread is working the gui and not the calculations

Comment: @XtremeBaumer would you be able to explain how to do that further? I am new to java swing... Also, I was thinking perhaps storing all my calculation related methods in a seperate java file, so when the equal button is clicked, it calls the methods in the other file instead. Would this help too? Or would I still have to create a new thread

Comment: you would still need a new thread. java does not create a new thread for every java file. it uses 1 thread to do all the work except you start a new one by yourself.

Comment: You have a non terminating while loop: `while (isDigit){ value = value + Character.toString(val.charAt(i));  }`
You should learn how to use your IDEs Debugger - it is easy to spot such mistakes when you step through your program. And you should strive to split your code in smaller classes - you mix parsing, calculating, GUI in one class, code written this way is hard to understand and test!

Comment: @GyroGearless that was the problem, thank you so much. I am not using an IDE hence why I'm having so many issues I suppose, I will definitely look into it. Please post your solution as the answer so I can mark you as the answer please.

Answer (score 1):

In stead of wrapping the call in a regular `Thread`, make use of Swingutilities. You will need to do this since Swing isn't threadsafe. This way you will still be working on the EDT.

```
 SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                try {
                    label2.setText(bracket(splitLabel(label.getText())));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Hi, it still seems to be freezing: 
  ActionListener button_eqListener = new ActionListener(){
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
     try {
      label2.setText(calculate(splitLabel(label.getText())));
     } catch (Exception f){
      f.printStackTrace();
     }
    });
   }
  };

Comment: `invokeLater()` alone does not start the calculation in its own thread - so this will also block.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to:

1. Use a separate `Thread` and use `SwingUtilities.inovkeLater()` to place the text field updates on the EDT, or
2. Use a `SwingWorker`, which has a built in API to support the above to features.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for complete information and working examples of a SwingWorker.

Answer (score -1):

In the method where you call the calculations method, wrap the call in this:

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){      
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                label2.setText(bracket(splitLabel(label.getText())));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
    }
```

this should solve the problem of the program freezing. if not pleasetell me

Comment: Where exactly should I store this? Inside the ActionListener for button_eq?

Comment: that is a possible place and also might be the best place for it

Comment: When I compile the following code, it tells me it cannot find the symbol "method printStacktrace()" in the location "variable e of type Exception".

     ActionListener button_eqListener = new ActionListener(){
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
         public void run(){
          try {
           label2.setText(bracket(splitLabel(label.getText())));
          } catch (Exception e){
           e.printStacktrace();
         }
         }
        });
        t.start();
       }
      };

Comment: the t from stacktrace must be capital. edited in my answer

Comment: The original `calculate()` returns a `String` which is discarded here?

Comment: Wouldn't it be even better to make use of `SwingUtilities.invokeLater();`?

Comment: This time it compiles, however the button_eq does nothing. After I click it, it doesn't continue onto the method, however it still allows me to click other buttons.

Comment: updated answer to fit the case the thread is started at clicking button

Comment: Note 2: SWING IS NOT THREADSAFE. Using a Thread this way would mean updating a GUI Element from outside the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - a no no. You should either use `SwingWorker` or `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` as suggested.

Comment: @Thibstars if I be honest, I did look up SwingWorker and SwingUtilities and when I tried to implement it into my code, it became confusing and messy. I couldn't really tell where to insert the code I found.

Comment: @GyroGearless I did look up examples of SwingWorker and tried to implement it into my code but I kept getting errors with the doInBackground method so I gave up :(

Comment: since i never worked with swingworker, you guys could maybe put up an answer using it

Comment: @XtremeBaumer, read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html). It explains why the EDT is important and has an example on using a SwingWorker. (1-) for the original answer which goes against all the advice in the above link.